# phonegap run android - Failed to execute aapt - what is this?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

Just starting to learn phonegap.
After setting up phonegap create and adding the [UPNP plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/Service-Discovery-DLNA-SSDP) as instructed, this error shows up.

```
~/phone/testing2$ phonegap run android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android ' ...
ANDROID_HOME=/home/arjun/Android/Sdk

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.


Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/loopj/android/android-async-http/1.4.9/android-async-http-1.4.9.pom


Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/cz/msebera/android/httpclient/4.3.6/httpclient-4.3.6.pom


Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/cz/msebera/android/httpclient/4.3.6/httpclient-4.3.6.jar


Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/loopj/android/android-async-http/1.4.9/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar


:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest


:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest


:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies


:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl


:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileLint


:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders


:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders


:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets


:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets


:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles


:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript


:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues


:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources


:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest


:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig


:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
/home/arjun/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.1/aapt: 3: /home/arjun/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string



FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:

Run with 
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.123 secs

Error: /home/arjun/phone/testing2/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/home/arjun/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.1/aapt: 3: /home/arjun/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I simply downloaded the Android studio, ran setup, added Android Kitkat as well, added the env variables and only then ran that phonegap command.

How to work past this error?

ALSO, how can I tell if phonegap would build/compile for Android 4.4? Since, the android studio has two platforms now, Nougat and Kitkat.

Comment: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace

Comment: It gives the same output.

Comment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string - You have a bad string somewhere ?

Comment: I checked with the author of UPNP plugin. There was a syntax error for sure in the plugin. It was promptly updated but even now I am getting the same error. No change in the output. Is there something something missing, from setup because I did not installed the emulator and in the bash.rc file I have mention only about the SDK path. Any other path is required?